# How to render HashMap key as attribute in XML?

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, jackson

I have a simple Bean that contains a `HashMap`. My goal is to show a `JSON` list with key-value references.

Problem: I want to use the same object to also show `XML` output. But keys of a map are converted to xml *elements*, which is not what I want. I'd like the map keys to be attributes in XML.

Is that possible without having to rewrite the code (I'd like to prevent having to create different objects each for json and xml)?

```
public class MyResponse {
    private Map<String, Obj> rooms;
}
```

Renders with:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public MyResponse rsp() {
        return rsp;
    }
}
```

as JSON:

```
"A11": {
  ...
},
"A12": {
  ...
}
```

as XML:

```
<A11>
  ...
</A11>
<A12>
  ...
</A12>
```

What I want in XML:

```
<room type="A11">
  ...
</room>
```

Comment: You don't show anything related to rendering so far, how are we to know what can you do to achieve your goal?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using `spring-web` framework that takes care of the rendering and uses `jackson` and `jaxb`.

Comment: In that case, you should define (un)marshalling schema for your class so it behaves as you want.

Comment: Can you give an example what you mean with "unmarshalling schema"?

Comment: Well, a schema would define what XML properties you object has and what those properties are themselves (those are often in `.xsd` files, at least as far as I encounter them). But for your needs I think you be better off with [defining](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-objectxml-mapping-example/) your own pair of [Marshaller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/oxm/Marshaller.html)/[Unmarshaller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/oxm/Unmarshaller.html) classes.